# Reading Call logs in Android

Tags: android, android-activity

In Android, I want to read call logs of a mobile. I am able to get/read some fields such as phone number, type of call, date, duration. But I am not able to read `PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID` or `PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME`. When I query for this field in the code, the app crashes during deployment.
Basically, I want a way to extract the phone number with which the call was made.

The code is :

```
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String strOrder = android.provider.CallLog.Calls.DATE + " DESC";
    /* Query the CallLog Content Provider */
    Cursor managedCursor = managedQuery(CallLog.Calls.CONTENT_URI, null,
            null, null, strOrder);
    int number = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.NUMBER);
    int type = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.TYPE);
    int date = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DATE);
    int duration = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.DURATION);
    int account = managedCursor.getColumnIndex(CallLog.Calls.PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME);
    sb.append("Call Log :");
    for(String temp : managedCursor.getColumnNames())
        sb.append(temp + ",");
    while (managedCursor.moveToNext()) {
        String phNum = managedCursor.getString(number);
        String callTypeCode = managedCursor.getString(type);
        String strcallDate = managedCursor.getString(date);
        Date callDate = new Date(Long.valueOf(strcallDate));
        String callDuration = managedCursor.getString(duration);
        String callType = null;
        int callcode = Integer.parseInt(callTypeCode);
        switch (callcode) {
            case CallLog.Calls.OUTGOING_TYPE:
                callType = "Outgoing";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.INCOMING_TYPE:
                callType = "Incoming";
                break;
            case CallLog.Calls.MISSED_TYPE:
                callType = "Missed";
                break;
        }
        String accountName = managedCursor.getString(account);
        sb.append("\nPhone Number:--- " + phNum + " \nCall Type:--- "
                + callType + " \nCall Date:--- " + callDate
                + " \nCall duration in sec :--- " + callDuration
                + " \nOwner :--- " + accountName);
        sb.append("\n----------------------------------");
    }
```

The logs are :

```
 12-20 22:48:27.431 3289-3289/com.example.oozie.phonebilloptimizer E/CursorWindow: Failed to read row 0, column -1 from a CursorWindow which has 955 rows, 34 columns.
12-20 22:48:27.441 3289-3289/com.example.oozie.phonebilloptimizer D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
12-20 22:48:27.461 3289-3289/com.example.oozie.phonebilloptimizer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                                    Process: com.example.oozie.phonebilloptimizer, PID: 3289
                                                                                    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.oozie.phonebilloptimizer/com.example.oozie.phonebilloptimizer.CallLogActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2303)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909)
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
                                                                                        at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
                                                                                        at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:438)
                                                                                        at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
                                                                                        at android.database.CursorWrapper.getString(CursorWrapper.java:114)
                                                                                        at com.example.oozie.phonebilloptimizer.CallLogActivity.getCallDetails(CallLogActivity.java:64)
                                                                                        at com.example.oozie.phonebilloptimizer.CallLogActivity.onCreate(CallLogActivity.java:27)
                                                                                        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5984)
                                                                                        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1105)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2256)
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2363) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:147) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1283) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
                                                                                        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5234) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                                                        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:909) 
                                                                                        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:704)
```

Comment: Include your code and the crash logs.

Answer (score 0):

[PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#PHONE_ACCOUNT_COMPONENT_NAME) and [PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#PHONE_ACCOUNT_ID) have been added in API level 21. Your cursor does not contain that columns, probably because you are using device with older API level.

If want phone number you can just use [CallLog.Calls#NUMBER](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/CallLog.Calls.html#NUMBER).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I hope this might work. But if I use API level 21, the app will be accessible to very less users

Comment: You can use CallLog.Calls#NUMBER.

Comment: NUMBER is for the person who is getting called. I am talking about the number or the identification of the person who place the call. I want to account for multiple-sims; this is my use-case